# bash: catching user input and do nearly identical command

Tags: bash

i'm trying to create a little text-game in shell to learn bash. 
i want to catch user input numbers 1 to n and echo the string between the () from the answer. i also want to make sure that the user did not put garbage in, so i choosed this code below, but it doesnt handle the string from the () part, i can handle, if there is any input but i cannot handle the differences from the input.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo -e "You are in front of the gardenhouse."
echo -e "\n"
echo -e "1 - forward (door.1)"
echo -e "2 - left (woods.2)"
echo -e "3 - right (water.3)"
while true
do
  # (1) 
  read -p "Which way to go right now? " benutzereingabe


  # handle the userinput
  case $benutzereingabe in
   [13]* ) echo "You walk to the $direction.  \n"

break;;

   [nN]* ) exit;;

   * )     echo "Only Answers (1 bis 3) are possible. \n";;
  esac
done
```

thanks for reading. i'm pretty sure there is a much better way to handle my needs. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It looks like this was translated with Google Translate. I can't tell what's being asked, specifically "i cannot handle the differences from the input." I know this isn't a German site, but could you maybe add the original German question below the original question?

Comment: @l0b0 is it ok to post a question in two languages? is there a meta post for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have at least two bugs:

1. `[13]` should be `[1-3]` or `[123]`
2. You can't `break` from a `case` statement; `;;` is enough.